# Angular 13 component loaded in iframe and ViewEncapsulation limitation

Tags: angular, iframe, sass, salesforce, bootstrap-5

My component, **DiscoveryComponent**, is dynamically loaded into an iframe hosted by my **AppComponent** but oddly, the font-family set in the component's SCSS file is not applied.

Below is how I load **DiscoveryComponent** into **AppComponent's** iframe. I explicitly import Bootstrap's SCSS in DiscoveryComponent's SCSS file and set the $font-family-base variable before loading Bootstrap.

**app.component.html**

```html
<iframe style="height: 500px; width: 100%;" #iframe></iframe>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'
import { DiscoveryComponent } from './discovery/discovery.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('iframe', {static: false}) iframe!: ElementRef
  doc: any

  public onLoad() {
    const iframe = <HTMLIFrameElement> this.iframe.nativeElement
    this.doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow
    this.createComponent()
  }

  private createComponent() {
    const component = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(DiscoveryComponent)
    component.location.nativeElement.id = 'discovery'
    this.doc.body.appendChild(component.location.nativeElement)
  }

  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.onLoad()
  }
}
```

**discovery.component.html**

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">I display using the Times font</div>
    <div class="col-6">So do I</div>
  </div
</div>
```

**discovery.component.scss**

```
$font-family-base: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";

@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

**discovery.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-discovery',
  templateUrl: './discovery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./discovery.component.scss']
})
export class DiscoveryComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Any thoughts as to why Bootstrap styles are loaded but the $font-family-base is not being applied?